# Sobolev spaces H^{k}, k an integer

Tags: inequalities

I have two questions:

1. is it true that we have equivalence between these two norms?

$$\lVert u\rVert_{H^{k}}^{2}\sim \lVert u\rVert_{L^{2}}^{2}+\sum_{\lvert \alpha\rvert=k} \lVert D^{\alpha}u\rVert_{L^{2}}^{2}$$

2. Is it true that we have this inequality and if it is true how can I prove it?

$$\sum_{\lvert \alpha\rvert=2k} \lVert D^{\alpha}u\rVert_{L^{2}}^{2}\le \lVert\Delta ^{k}u\rVert_{L^{2}}^{2},$$
where $\Delta=\sum\limits_{i \le N}\dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x_{i}^{2}}$ and here I work on a bounded smooth domain $\Omega \subset \mathbf{R^{N}}$.

Comment: Both of them are true on the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (take the Fourier transform). Second is false if we consider just $W_2^n(\Omega)$ because $u$ might be a restriction of the harmonic function to $\Omega$, but the first one should be true for $\Omega$, but I don't know the reference.

Comment: thank for your answer @Aleksei Kulikov i  have other hypthseis for the second inequality  if u is the solution of heat equation it will be true? imean if $u_{t}=\Delta u$        thank you